# Symfony lost session on Service

Tags: session, symfony, mobile-webkit

I have a UserProvider for the Lexik bundle and check if the user exists through the session but there is a problem when I make certain request the sessions lose the value someone knows because this happens.

Service

```
app.user_provider:
    class: ApiBundle\Security\Userprovider
    arguments: ["@session","@switchconnection","@doctrine.orm.entity_manager" , "@doctrine.dbal.default_connection" , "@doctrine"]
```

My provider

```
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserProviderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\UsernameNotFoundException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\UnsupportedUserException;
use ApiBundle\Entity\Utilizador;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Session;    
public function __construct(Session $session,$switchconnection ,\Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager $em , \Doctrine\DBAL\Connection $dbalConnection , \Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Registry $doctrine) {
    $this->session = $session;
    $this->switchconnection = $switchconnection;
    $this->em = $em;
    $this->connection = $dbalConnection;
    $this->doctrine = $doctrine;
    } 

    public function loadUserByUsername($username)
    {
    if($this->session->get("currentuser") == $username){    
        $this->switchconnection->switchDatabase($this->session->get("dbconnection"), $this->connection , $this->doctrine);
        $conn =  $this->em->getConnection();
        $stmt = $conn->prepare(".....");
        $stmt->bindParam(1, $username);
        $stmt->execute();
        $results = $stmt->fetchAll();
        $count = count($results);
            if($count != 0)
            {  
                $user= new Utilizador();
                $user->setUsername($results[0]['username']);
                $user->setEmail($results[0]['email']);
                return $user;
            }
            }
    throw new UsernameNotFoundException(sprintf('Username "%s" does not exist.', $username) );
    }
```

I also checked that in the var/session/dev folder there is a session register with 2 Phpsession almost identical.

[image]

**Update 1**

Important information this only happens in webkit browsers

Answer (score 0):

Please include `session` component in your `ApiBundle\Security\Userprovider`.

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Session;
```

I think you forgot to add session component.

**Update-1**

User `service_container` by passing it in service. For me its working fine.

**services.yml**

```
app.user_provider:
    class: ApiBundle\Security\Userprovider
    arguments: ["@service_container", "@session","@switchconnection","@doctrine.orm.entity_manager" , "@doctrine.dbal.default_connection" , "@doctrine"]
```

**Provider**

```
protected $container;
protected $session;

public function __construct($container, Session $session,$switchconnection ,\Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager $em , \Doctrine\DBAL\Connection $dbalConnection , \Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Registry $doctrine) {

    $this->container = $container;
    $this->session = $container->get('session');

}
```

Comment: I have added sorry I have not entered the imports in the question